# How to find specific entry in array response?

Tags: rest-assured

My return JSON is an anonymous array that looks like this:

```
[
    "name" : "John",
    "age" : 26,
    "likes" : "Ice Cream"
],
[
    "name" : "Jake",
    "age" : 26,
    "likes" : "Pizza"
]
```

Based on this I want to get the name of entry in which the age is 26 and the likes is "Pizza" (so "Jake" in this case). How do I do that?

So far I've got this but it's just plain wrong, as the hasItem doesn't look at all whether the two items are in the same collection. Also the response simply gives me everything.

```
String name = given().contentType("application/json").when().
                get(base + "/persons").
                then().
                statusCode(200).
                body("age", hasItem(26)).
                body("likes", hasItem("Pizza")).
                extract().response();
```

How would you do that?

Comment: try changing your return structure to 
[{
    "name" : "John",
    "age" : 26,
    "likes" : "Ice Cream"
},
{
    "name" : "Jake",
    "age" : 26,
    "likes" : "Pizza"
}]

Comment: Oh sorry, that was the case actually. I forgot the curly brackets in this code. Still doesn't eliminate the problem of finding the correct entry though.

Answer (score 0):

With JsonPath, you can try this:

```
Response response = given().contentType("application/json").get(base + "/persons");
response.then().statusCode(200);

String name = JsonPath.with(response.getBody()).getString("$[?(@.age == 26 && @.likes eq 'Pizza')].name");
Assert.assertEquals("Jake", name);
```

I am not 100% sure that will work, but something like it will: https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/1.4/com/jayway/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html

Without JsonPath, you could do this:

```
Response response = given().contentType("application/json")get(base + "/persons");
response.then().statusCode(200);

List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(response.getBody().as(Person[].class));
Assert.assertTrue(!people.isEmpty());

for(Person person : people) {
  if(person.getAge() == 26 && person.getLikes().equals("Pizza")) {
    Assert.assertEquals("Jake", person.getName());
  }
}
```